# Windows 10 using wrong DNS server

Tags: windows-10, router, dns, dhcp

I have a local DNS server. My router is configured to provide both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of the local DNS server, but regardless, the DHCP server is *also* the DNS server so AFAIK the router plays no part in this.

The DHCP/DNS server is `192.168.2.100`. Upon connection to the network, windows uses:
[image]

this is incorrect. So I ran `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` and the result is the same.

So I installed wireshark and checked what was going on. The first (and only) DHCP request is handled with this reply:
[image]

So I know that:

1. The DHCP request is being sent to the correct IP
2. The DHCP ACK is being received and contains the correct DNS server information
3. Windows is still using google DNS servers.

In the past, I used google One's VPN service but when I realized it forced the DNS server to theirs, I uninstalled it and took a hot shower.

I am on windows 10 v 22H2 build 19045.3930. All other non-windows devices behave correctly.

Any ideas why windows is being so Microsofty?

Comment: Screenshots of the IPv4 adapter properties would be helpful, explicitly, the tab that shows the proxy and DNS options

Comment: I know your IP on the network adapter is set to DHCP, but make sure the nameservers are also set. To be 100% sure, you can check the registry for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\\{Network_Adaptor_GUID}\NameServer` and if it is blank, then it set to automatic, otherwise youll find the google dns addresses there

Comment: @Ramhound Holy shoot! The IPV4 adapter properties had the google DNS server set. What sorcery is this? The dns was working fine a week ago. Is there any software that is known to sneak these shenanigans in?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart - Software can configure your DNS servers and you did say you used Google Ones VPN service and stopped because it was using their DNS service. That’s probably why.